# Connecting Django to MSSQL Server Express 2014 database

Tags: python, django, sql-server-2014-express

I'm running Django (1.8) off a Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS), using VirtualEnv and Pip.

```
pip freeze

astroid==1.5.3
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.4
configparser==3.5.0
Django==1.8
django-mssql==1.8
django-pyodbc==1.1.1
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.0.0
django-sqlserver==1.11
enum34==1.1.6
future==0.16.0
inflection==0.3.1
isort==4.2.15
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
peewee==3.1.5
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
pyad==0.5.15
pylint==1.7.4
pyodbc==4.0.19
PyPiwi==1.8
python-tds==1.8.2
pytz==2017.2
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
South==1.0.2
wrapt==1.10.11
```

I'm currently struggling with sqlserver_ado ENGINE and am using it because it seems to be the most popular, but am aware of django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 and sql_server.pyodbc, and am willing to jump ship at the drop of a hat.

So my DATABASES definition looks like this:

```
'default': {
    'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': 'HOSTNAME\\SQLEXPRESS',
    'PORT': '56988',
    'USER': 'mssql_name',
    'PASSWORD': 'mssql_pw',}
```

Django runs with this information. Fantastic. But when I hit my function,

```
    def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [GM].[Acct]")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

I get an exception: **When using DATABASE PORT, DATABASE HOST must be an IP address.** If I try to change the host to an IP address, Django won't run, and spews this:

```
  File "/home/jason/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlserver_ado/dbapi.py", line 183, in connect
    import pythoncom
```

I've tried pip install pypipwin32.

When I run django using python3, I get **ImportError: No module named 'sqlserver_ado'**

If anyone is able to nudge me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

For the sake of completeness, here are some of my attempts with tsql, but again, my connection is constantly refused:

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[DARKTOWER_SQLEXPRESS]
Description=Test
Driver=FreeTDS
Database=DB
Servername=DARKTOWER\\SQLEXPRESS
port=56988
TDS_Version=7.2
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[ODBC]

    Trace = Yes
    TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log

    [FreeTDS]
    Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
    Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
    Setup =  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
    UsageCount = 1
```

**/etc/freetds/freetds.conf**

```
[DARKTOWER]
        host = DARKTOWER\\SQLEXPRESS
        port = 56988
        tds version = 7.2
```

Got some success using these settings. Not a fan of having to use a domain account...

```
'default': {      
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', #'sqlserver_ado', #'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'DARKTOWER\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '56988',
        'USER': 'DOMAIN\\Jason',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'NAME': 'DB',
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
         'OPTIONS':{
              'driver': 'FreeTDS',
              'host_is_server': True,
              'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.2',},
     }
```

I'm still interested in others' solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver',
    'HOST': 'aws2.myhost.com',
    'PORT': '1433',
    'USER': 'xxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'nbxxxa$$sxxxxxts$$xxxx',
    'NAME': 'MyDBName',
```

instead of what you have. I have the same sql pip entries as you, and that is how my settings.py looks when I connect to sql server

Comment: Not having any luck with this, my login keeps failing. Which version of Django are you using? Verified the Port via Configuration Manager, even specified the instance so I wouldn't need the port. Created more users via SQL management studio. nada

Comment: I am using 1.11